# Allow user to select the location of a Custom Panel

Tags: python, scripting, interface

Is it possible to allow the user to select the Location of a custom Panel which I have created using python in Blender.
Generally, I found that the location of a panel is set outside the Function in a class, and therefore I cannot use any decision statements!

I have already created an enum property which can allow to select the different locations. But I don't know how to use it!

Comment: There is only append and prepend, and other addons might try to do the same. it's difficult to force a panel location when your add-on is out in the wild. related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24041/how-i-can-define-the-order-of-the-panels

Comment: Yes, I even I thought the same thing, but was just wondering if it was possible :)

Comment: The point made in the other post is valid I think. If people want your panels in a specific place they will save their layouts the way the like and use that as a default .blend .